# using google geolocation array of coordinates and duration from start to end to calculate the pace

Tags: javascript, geolocation

i have a fitness app that tracks a runner and at the end shows the distance and the time of running and drowse a line on the map using google map and geolocation api.
i need to calculate the pace according to those parameters.

lets say the total distance of the run was 7km and the duration of the run was 37 minuts, what would be the correct way to calculate the pace so that the pace should be correct and would be shown in minutes:seconds formation and not 5.281.. 
this is what i got for now:

```
function get_Runtime() { //this function takes the duration and convert to total of seconds
    var sec = parseInt(document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML)
    var minute = parseInt((document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML) * 60)
    var total_time = (sec + minute);
    return total_time;
}

function average_pace(distance) { // this function takes duration and devide by distance
    var avgnum = get_Runtime() / distance
    return avgnum.toPrecision(3);
}
```

the outcome will always be like 2.322 but what i need is to convert that to minutes : seconds like 2:34
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get minutes divide seconds by 60. To get minutes:seconds, do

```
parseInt(seconds/60) + ':' + seconds%60
```

This will output something like:

```
avgnum = 567;
var minutes = parseInt(avgnum/60) //9;
var seconds = avgnum%60 //27;
var formatted = minutes + ':' + seconds;
```

The operator I used is called the `modulo`. This takes the remainder of division, so `7%3 = 1`, `8%4 = 0`, etc.

`parseInt` takes the floor value of a decimal.

Comment: i have already multiplied the minute by 60 in the third line, why did you multiply it again?

Comment: Oops. That was a mistake. Just fixed it.